# Increase node memory using npm package.json script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, electron, electron-builder

If you want to increase the memory limit in node, the option to be passed will be:

`node --max-old-space-size=4096 yourFile.js`

But in my scenario I am using yarn, my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "productName": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app/main.js",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "package-win": "npm run build && build --win --x64",
    "package-mac": "npm run build && build --mac",
    ...
  },
  ...
```

I execute `yarn package-win` on a windows machine to invoke electron-builder for my electron app built with react.js. But I get always `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` Due to out of memory. In my mac also got the `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` Error but still got the packages generated (how? I don't know) when invoking `yarn package-mac`.

I search a lot on how to use the `--max-old-space-size=4096` option, but I haven't found anything that works.

I tried `"package-win": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 npm run build && build --win --x64",` But the path have problems locating npm. Even if I use which npm, still `which` is not recognized.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to myself: Using this options in `package-win` is wrong. As package-win executes the build task, then:

```
"build": "npm run build-main && npm run build-renderer",
...
"build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --max_old_space_size=6144 --optimize_for_size --stack_size=6144 --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.main.prod.js --progress --profile --colors",
"build-renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node --max_old_space_size=6144 --optimize_for_size --stack_size=6144 --trace-warnings -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.renderer.prod.js --progress --profile --colors",
```

That way it works!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use option in package-win.
The way you should use-

```
    "build-ts-prod": "node --max-old-space-size=1024 
    ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --skipLibCheck --diagnostics",
```